# The creation of one of the array of multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

There are three array of the form:

```
Array (
    [0] => NAME
    [1] => NAME
    [n] => n
)
Array (
    [0] => DATE
    [1] => DATE
    [n] => n
)
Array (
    [0] => TEXT
    [1] => TEXT
    [n] => n
)
```

As possible to combine these three arrays in one of the next species?

```
Array(
    Array (
        [0] => NAME
        [1] => DATE
        [2] => TEXT
    )
    Array (
        [0] => NAME
        [1] => DATE
        [2] => TEXT
    )
        Array (
        [0] => NAME
        [1] => DATE
        [2] => TEXT
    )
    and etc.
)
```

Arrays build with the use of library [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)
*that's the way*

```
// Search for the name
$array_nameNews = array();
foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div h2 a') as $element) {    
    $nameNews = $element->innertext;
    $array_nameNews[] = $nameNews;
}

// Search the date
$array_dateNews = array();
foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div div.postdate') as $element) {
    $dateNews = $element->innertext;
    $array_dateNews[] = $dateNews;
}

// Search text
$array_textNews = array();
foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div div.postdate span') as $element) {
    $textNews = $element->innertext;
    $array_textNews[] = $textNews;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `array_merge()` and your end-result arrays as others suggest, but you should do this instead:

```
$articles = array();
foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div') as $art_elem) {
    $article = array(
        'name' => $art_elem->find('h2 a', 0)->plaintext,
        'date' => $art_elem->find('div.postdate', 0)->plaintext,
        'text' => $art_elem->find('div.postdate span')->innertext,
    );
    $articles[] = $article;
}
```

Two reasons:

1. It's much clearer what you are actually trying to accomplish.
2. It is less brittle. Suppose a particular 'div.narrow_column div' element lacks one of these fields? In this case, your three arrays might be different sizes, or the items in the array may not correspond to other ones with the same index. If you iterate the container elements once and grab the items you need within the `$art_elem` context, you can degrade gracefully even when some items are missing.

Comment: Argh, almost finished writing my own answer with the same approach, then saw yours. ) +1: of course, it's better to fill the array correctly the first time than transform it some ways.

Comment: Although I answered with an alternative, +1 to this from me too.

Comment: It's about super :) thank you very Much for the recommendation of the bearer of such an approach, THANK you THANK you THANK you :)) Really cool!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this  by [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) — Merge one or more arrays

try like

```
  $result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/PaIdUXJT)

Comment: thank you for the advice, most likely array_merge not work because I need the answer a little bit of a different kind, please take a look an example in my description

Answer (score 0):

You'd be looking at something like this

```
<?php
$formatted = array();
foreach ($array_nameNews as $key => $news) {
  $one_piece = new array();
  $one_piece['NAME'] = $news;
  $one_piece['DATE'] = $array_dateNews[$key];
  $one_piece['TEXT'] = $array_textNews[$key];
  $formatted[] = $one_piece
}
```

Comment: tell you the secret, all the same to your solution, so I've got some peculiarities of the formation of the initial array! Thank you again :) I apologize for something that can put you a plus, because of my modest reputation!

Answer (score 0):

First of all `Array` and `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual` are different things..
In case of array you should try this

```
$first = array('1','2','3');
$second = array('11','22','33');
$third = array('111','222','333');

 for($i=0;$i<count($first);$i++)
 {
  $result[] = array($first[$i],$second[$i],$third[$i]); 
 }
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo "</pre>";exit;
```

Sorry, if you don't like my wording.

Comment: in any case, and thank you for participating, I will take your code to note!

Comment: and also see the count($first) limit because in this case all array element is same otherwise you want to find bigger array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the arrays always have the same number of elements

```
$t = count($array_nameNews);
$sorted = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$t, $i++) {
    $sorted[] = array(
        $array_nameNews[$i],
        $array_dateNews[$i],
        $array_textNews[$i],
    );
 }
```